# Sub query to fetch the highest value

Tags: mysql, sql

Input

```
+-------+---------+----------+
| Name  | Country | State    |
+-------+---------+----------+
| jon   | US      | Chicago  |
+-------+---------+----------+
| kathy | US      | CA       |
+-------+---------+----------+
| linda | US      | LA       |
+-------+---------+----------+
| harry | UK      | wales    |
+-------+---------+----------+
| steve | UK      | scotland |
+-------+---------+----------+
| ram   | India   | ap       |
+-------+---------+----------+
| jai   | India   | ka       |
+-------+---------+----------+
| raju  | India   | ap       |
+-------+---------+----------+
| ravi  | India   | mp       |
+-------+---------+----------+
```

Iam not able to pass the country with highest count(india) using the below query as it is returning 2(country & count) values. Please correct me.

```
select name from table a 
where a.country in 
(SELECT country, COUNT(*) as c FROM table b 
GROUP BY country 
ORDER BY c DESC LIMIT 1);
```

Output:

The details  of the state (under the highest counted country-india) whose count is the highest in the same table should be displayed.

```
+---------+-------+----+
| ram     | india | ap |
+---------+-------+----+
| raju    | india | ap |
+---------+-------+----+
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason for returning `| raju  | India   | ap       |` not other from the group ?

Comment: Yes. I want the state with highest count.

Comment: Can you please tell me which type of sql query you use (SQL Server syntax, Oracle Syntax, etc..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECT country, COUNT(*) as c FROM table b 
GROUP BY country 
ORDER BY c DESC LIMIT 1;

UPDATE: This should work

```
select state,count(*) c2 from a t1
INNER JOIN (
SELECT country, COUNT(*) as c FROM a t1 GROUP BY country ORDER BY c DESC LIMIT 1) t2 on t1.country = t2.country
GROUP BY state ORDER BY c2 DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: This is half done.. The highest country should be passed and then the records with the highest count of state should be the output.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select * from table e
where e.state in
(select d.state from table a 
where a.country in 
(SELECT country  FROM table b 
 GROUP BY country 
 ORDER BY count(*) DESC LIMIT 1);
 GROUP BY state 
 ORDER BY count(*) DESC LIMIT 1);
```

Comment: That will work for the example data provided, but not for all cases - suppose all 3 `US` entries had `state = 'Chicago'` - your query would be looking for country = 'India' and state = 'Chicago' and would hence return no results.

Comment: @SimarjeetSinghPanghlia  got this error.  SubQuery can contain only 1 item in Select List.

Comment: @SimarjeetSinghPanghlia  nested subqueries not working for me.. Any otheer way.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.name,c.country,c.state,
FROM table c
INNER JOIN (SELECT a.country,a.state,count(*) statecount
            FROM table a 
            INNER JOIN (SELECT b.country, COUNT(*) as countrycount
                        FROM table b 
                        GROUP BY b.country 
                        ORDER BY countrycount DESC LIMIT 1) b ON a.country = b.country
            GROUP BY a.country,a.state
            ORDER BY a.statecount DESC LIMIT 1) d ON c.country = d.country
                                                  AND c.state = d.state
```

Answer (score 0):

i tried it in sql server and that statement work for me:

```
select * from [table] a 
where a.country in 
(SELECT top 1 country FROM [table] b 
GROUP BY country 
ORDER BY  COUNT(*) DESC)
```

I guess that you use Postgre or somthing similer, so try this one:

```
select * from [table] a 
where a.country in 
(SELECT country FROM [table] b 
GROUP BY country 
ORDER BY  COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 1)
```

If you tell me the SQL language type, i will be able to give you the exact query

Answer (score -1):

This is mssql Query you can convert according you.

`select top 1 unitid as n, count (*) as co  from npcstatus where unitid is not null Group by unitid having count (*)>1  order by co desc`

This query will give you unitid with most occurrence.

You can modify as you like.